# How to run WPS WPA TESTER in BlueStacks or MuMemu?

Tags: connection, wifi-configuration, virtual-wifi

**WIFI WPA WPS TESTER** works on a rooted device. Intentionally I don't want my device to get rooted. So I want way to overcome this problem. I have tried to run this software but it doesn't connect to external WiFi outside the virtual Android.

I have googled this but doesn't got any solution for this. So I am asking this question and just want the solution of running WPA WPS TESTER on the virtual Android platform like BlueStacks and MuMemu.

If you have faced this problem before and overcame it !! Then *Please* share the solution.

Comment: Tester programs need greater than normal access to the hardware. This is why it needs Root access on an Android device. Bluestacks cannot present actual hardware to the software you run on it because it has to interpret all of the commands and requests into something compatible with the host system, and so it is likely intentionally limited to the basic approved hardware functions common to Android devices.

Comment: Ohhhhhh  I see !!